# "to use" vs "in using" vs "in usage"

Tags: word-choice, infinitives

> Italian people have some difficulties **in usage** of the word "interchange" and the phrase "each other".

When I wrote that sentence some doubts arose to my mind in reference to the highlighted words "in usage".

I excluded that it was possible to write "to use", but I don't know why. Afterwards I thought that I could have written "in using", but, after some thoughts, I excluded this option, too; then I decided to write "in usage", even when some uncertainty remained.

Could anybody enlighten me on this problem? Is there some suggestion that might help incompetent speakers, as I am, in cases like this?

Comment: *Uncompetent* is an obsolete word that is not standard in modern English.  *Incompetent* is a common word, but I wouldn't use it to describe you.

Comment: @snail, thank you in all senses. I love to hear your words. (PS: I edited the question :)

Comment: "I excluded that..." as used above does not seem right. Maybe you meant "I concluded that..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write:

> Italian people have some difficulties ***with using*** the word "interchange" and the phrase "each other".

To *have difficulty with* something is a common phrase to describe someone who has trouble doing something.  I wouldn't say "have difficulties in."

If you wanted to use "usage" instead of using, you could write it this way, though it sounds a bit more formal:

> Italian people have some difficulties ***with the usage of*** the word "interchange" and the phrase "each other".

You can either have *difficulty using* something, or have *difficulty with the usage of* something.  I'm sure there are also other acceptable variants of the sentence, but I think this covers the possibilities you've mentioned!

Comment: @snailplane LOL I was rereading my answer and just caught and edited that as you commented!

Comment: @snailplane Thanks ;)  That's what I get for copy-pasting the sentence! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "None of the above". To me, the most natural ([KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) phrasing is:

> *Italians have [some] difficulty **using** the word "interchange" and the phrase "each other".*

Apart from it being unnecessary verbosity, I think using *people* there sounds decidely "odd". For the record, [Italians have difficulty](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22performance%20ended%20with%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&ds=bo&pq=%22are%20expected%20not%20to%22&cp=14&gs_id=6u&xhr=t&q=%22Italians%20have%20difficulty%22&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22Italians%20have%20difficulty%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k&fp=7887a906c76385b1&biw=1419&bih=739) - 247 hits in Google Books, but [Italian people have difficulty](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22performance%20ended%20with%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Italian%20people%20have%20difficulty%22&oq=%22Italian%20people%20have%20difficulty%22&gs_l=serp.3...6333.8316.3.9217.8.8.0.0.0.2.222.645.7j0j1.8.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.7zSBzJovWYE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k&fp=7887a906c76385b1&biw=1419&bih=739) - no hits at all.

I personally wouldn't include the word *some*, because idiomatically native speakers very often use *some* semi-facetiously to mean *a great deal of* in such contexts, but that's probably not OP's intended sense. It's actually more likely that what's intended is ***Some*** Italians have difficulty...

Arguably some might say plural *difficulties* implies Italians face *more than one* different "kind" of difficulty using the terms. But even if that were so I wouldn't bother trying to make such a fine distinction.